# How can I use ILMERGE in a post-script build without hardcoding all of my DLL names?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, ilmerge

I'd like to specify all DLL's in the current directory except for the $(TargetFileName). Not sure how post-build works in visual studio or if there's a way to build a string to put into that command. Here's what I have so far:

```
cd $(OutDir)
mkdir merged
ilmerge.exe "$(TargetFileName)" "1.dll" "2.dll" "3.dll" "etc.dll" 
   "/out:merged\$(TargetName)Merged.dll" 
   /target:library /internalize /xmldocs 
   /targetplatform:v4,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use MSBuild.ILMerge.Task Nuget package...
or switch to Costura.Fody (if it's an .EXE)